# How to install libimobiledevice latest version on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, iphone, ios

How can I install [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/) latest version on Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's available through the default 18.04 repositories, so simply:

`sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice6 libimobiledevice-dev`

The latest stable release is 1.2.0, according to libimobiledevice [homepage](http://www.libimobiledevice.org) and [GitHub page](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/releases). 18.04 is bundled with version 1.2.1:

```
$ apt-cache madison libimobiledevice-dev  
libimobiledevice-dev | 1.2.1~git20171128.5a854327+dfsg-0.1 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```